# Worker thread communication protocol

Tags: node.js, node-modules, libuv, node-worker-threads

I stumbled upon worker threads in NodeJS and I started investigating on lower level abstraction how intercommunication and data sharing works between them, especially `postMessage` function that is being used to send message data between threads.

Looking at this line of code `const { Worker, isMainThread, parentPort } = require('worker_threads');` one would guess that it uses sockets in order to communicate as keyword port is being used, but I found no open port connections when searching them trough command prompt.

I want to understand what communication protocol is worker_thread mechanism using? Is it TCP or its some other mechanism of sharing data and messages in between threads? This is based on a research that I want to commit myself in order to understand efficiency of transmitting large amount of data in between worker_threads versus ICP communication between child processes using memory sharing/TCP.

Comment: You can always crack open the [nodejs source code](https://github.com/nodejs/node) and see for yourself.

Comment: @jfriend00 It's perhaps a bit much to expect someone to be able to find the relevant code in a repository which is not small by any sense of the imagination

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant - Yes, it is a bit daunting, but massively useful and worth learning how to find things in there, not just for this one issue, but going forward.  I go in there all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Workers don't communicate with their parents with any sort of TCP / IP or other interprocess communication protocol. The messages passed between workers, and between workers and parents, pass data back and forth directly. Workers and their parents share a single address space and V8 instance.

[`.postMessage()` looks like this](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html#worker_threads_port_postmessage_value_transferlist), where `transferList` is optional.

```
port.postMessage(value, transferList)
```

The items in the first parameter are [cloned](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm), and copies passed from the sender to the receiver of the message.

The items in the second parameter are passed without cloning them. Only certain array-style data types can be transferred this way. The sender loses access to these items and the receiver gains access. This saves the cloning time and makes it much quicker to pass large data structures like images. This sort of messaging works in both browser and nodejs code.

Child processes can pass data back and forth from the spawned process to the spawning process. That data is copied and pushed through the interprocess communication method set up at spawning time. In many cases the IPC mechanism uses OS-level pipes; those are as efficient as any IPC mechanism, especially on UNIX-derived OSs. Child processes do not share memory with parents, so they can't use a `transferList` change-of-ownership scheme directly.

Comment: I understood based on a lot of articles that every each worker thread have its own heap, garbage collector as well as its own instance of V8 as well as event loop trough libuv. Based on this information i assumed that they communicate trough sockets as i couldn't understand how could they possibly communicate if they don't share memory directly in memory address space? `A WorkerThread is an entirely new instance of the V8 Javascript interpreter`,
`In Node.js, each worker will have its own instance of V8 and Event Loop. `

Comment: While some sources inform that worker threads don't share the same JavaScript language space, it seems, however that they can share memory, according to the official documentation: **Unlike child_process or cluster, worker_threads can share memory. They do so by transferring ArrayBuffer instances or sharing SharedArrayBuffer instances.**